# Trouble with simple htaccess RewriteRule to remove %23 from end of url

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I started seeing 404 errors in my logs for urls like:

```
http://site.example.com/foo/bar.html%23anchor
```

Clearly the #anchor was being encoded (probably in someone else's email that I can't control) resulting in broken links. The anchor links are not that important, but I don't want my users seeing 404 pages. I thought I could fix this with a simple rewrite, but nothing I have tried has worked and none of the SO answers I looked at worked.

The rewrite codes I tried worked perfectly in RegExr and regex101, but when I try it in my .htaccess, the bad link still results in a 404 error. I have other RewriteRules working, but I can't seem to remove the unwanted %23anchor from the end of the request.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /site

## Externally redirect non-canonical domain requests to canonical domain. ###
## This rule works ###
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

## This rule doesn't work ###
RewriteRule ^(\.html)(%23)(.*)$ $1 [R=302,NE,L]
```

I need to change this:
`http://site.example.com/foo/bar.html%23anchor`

into this:
`http://site.example.com/foo/bar.html`

What am I missing?

Comment: `RewriteRule "^(.+?\.html)\#" $1 [R=302,L]` NE means no escaped result url-string

Comment: This rule resulted in `http://site.example.com/site/foo/bar.html`. It did strip the malformed anchor off of the end, but still resulted in a 404. Notice the extra "site" caused by the RewriteBase rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all of your suggestions, but none of them solved the initial problem. Because the **RewriteBase** rule affects all relative rewrites, I could not see a way to write this rule as I originally intended. In the end the only thing that seemed to work was to rewrite to an absolute path. This is the rule I ended up with. It is not flexible and only works for this page, but at least it fixes the specific broken link I am currently trying to correct:

`RewriteRule ^(.*bar\.html)\x23.*$ http://site.example.com/foo/bar.html [R=302,NE,L,NC]`

The above rule rewrites this: `http://site.example.com/foo/bar.html%23anchor`

to this: `http://site.example.com/foo/bar.html`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing everything in front of ".html". Try this rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.html)(%23)(.*)$ $1 [R=302,NE,L]
```

https://regex101.com/r/fV3oU3/1

Comment: Since I'm not allowed to add a comment to anubhavas answer below, I' doing it here..... @anubhava the questioner wanted to cut everything after the %23 including the %23... Your Rewrite will add everything that follows after the %23 to the replacement. So you should remove the $2.

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought should have worked as well and it works as expected in RegEx101. But when applied via htaccess, it results in `http://site.example.com/foo/bar.html%23anchor`: the original bad link. This rule seems to have no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your last rule with this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?\.html)\x23 /$1 [R=302,NE,L,NC]
```

`%23` is matches by `\x23` in `RewriteRule`.

Comment: This rule resulted in `http://site.example.com/site/foo/bar.htmlanchor` and a 404 error. It correctly removed the %23 but retained the "anchor" text and was also affected by the RewriteBase rule and added the extra "site" subdir.

Comment: Thanks, that did remove the anchor string from the end, but still resulted in a 404 due to the RewriteBase rule adding a subdir:
`http://site.example.com/SITE/foo/bar.html`

Comment: If that's the case you can just add `http://...` before target, as in the updated answer.